# RichTextBox set/change underline color (\ulcN) and underline style (e.g. \ulwave) for selection

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, styling, underline

I made my rich text box already accepting the \ulc*N* and the ul style tags (e.g. \ulwave, \ulth ...), but I could not figure out how to set them through code for the selected text (like: `richTextBox.SelectionFont = someFont;` for the font). I already tried modifying the Rtf and SelecedRtf property of the richTextBox directly but could not get it to work properly.

I though of two methods like:

```
static void SetSelectionUnderlineColor (this RichTextBox richTextBox, Color color)
static void SetSelectionUnderlineStyle (this RichTextBox richTextBox, 
                                        UnderLineStyle style)
```

which then sets the underline color / style for the currently selected text in the rich text box. The SetSelectionUnderlineColor method may also have to add a new color to the color table of the rich text box.

Example:

```
richTextbox = new RichEdit50(); //Used code for RichEdit50 class below

richTextbox.Text = "Test\nTest2";

richTextbox.Select(0, 2);
richTextbox.SetSelectionUnderlineStyle(UnderLineStyle.Wave);
richTextbox.SetSelectionUnderlineColor(Color.Red);

richTextbox.Select(5, 2);
richTextbox.SetSelectionUnderlineStyle(UnderLineStyle.Thick);
richTextbox.SetSelectionUnderlineColor(Color.Green);

richTextbox.Select(7, 3);
richTextbox.SetSelectionUnderlineStyle(UnderLineStyle.Continuous);

richTextbox.Select(richTextbox.Text.Length, 0);
```

Should show some thing like this:

[image: Expected outcome]

Currently I'm using the following code to create a rich text box that supports the \ulc*N* tag to change the underline color:

```
public class RichEdit50 : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary (string lpFileName);

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams prams = base.CreateParams;
            if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                prams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
            }
            return prams;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope it is useful for anyone who may need it.

I tried to post the **RichTextBoxEx** C# class here but exceeded the 30000 limit so download it from [https://github.com/heliwave/QuranCode](https://github.com/heliwave/QuranCode/)

You will find in the *Tools\Controls* folder together with **ListBoxEx.cs** and **PictureBoxEx.cs**.

See the full open-source C# library in action at [http://qurancode.com](https://qurancode.com/).